# Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.3.0

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I updated Flutter version to 2.2.0 now I am facing some issues

```
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.3.0 and mockito >=4.1.2 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7 depends on test_api ^0.2.19-nullsafety, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with mockito >=4.1.2 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7.
```

Comment: Use a newer version of mockito?  The current version of mockito uses `test_api: >=0.2.1 <0.5.0`.

Comment: I have tried to upgrade and downgrade the current version of mockito, but no luck.

Comment: Provide your `pubspec.yaml`.